# WPF - Load and change xaml in run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF.

I'm trying to load a xaml file following **[this 
 Microsoft tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashish/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml)**.

[image: result]

As you can see, it works!

But I want a few additional things:

When I change some styling (e.g. change a button's height from `82` to `100`), I want it to change automatically, but not run again.

What should I do?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Are you asking how to update the XAML in Visual Studio and have those changes automatically show up in your application without restarting it? That's not possible. Perhaps you can clarify.

Comment: I mean update the external XAML file in run-time, Next refresh app. it will change automatically, but not run again.